# Best messaging tool to control a bunch of computer?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to have the following setup. One computer gets a bunch of usernames and passwords from somewhere. I then want these pairs to be distributed to a bunch of other computers which will then login into those accounts and do some work. I don't want to just send 1/N of the pairs to each of the N computers, because different accounts might take different amounts of time to finish. I would like to have some sort of messaging tool in the master computer which the other computers then subscribe to to receive user/pass pairs and which then acknowledge when the jobs are finish to receive some more.

What tool should I use for this? RabbitMQ? Can it support a sort of circular queue, in that the last job finish goes into the back of the queue for an infinitely long running loop?

Comment: This may be better for http://programmers.stackexchange.com but asking to recommend an offsite resource or tool is offtopic for that site as well.

Comment: @clcto This question is off-topic at Programmers as well. Please do not recommend asking at other sites unless you are extremely familiar with that site's guidelines.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool. library, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic here, as is clearly stated in the [help/on-topic]. In addition, this site is for programming related questions, and your question has nothing to do with programming whatsoever.

Comment: Ok then, how do you suggest controlling PROGRAMS without a messaging tool?

Comment: There are about two quite same question per month asking to recommend a messaging tool. Such questions are off-topic, at least for SO. Without any particular knowledge about project needs, infrastructure, platform, etc. it couldn't be answered anyway.